# Why prepared statements don't allow fields and table names as parameters?

Tags: database, hibernate, jdbc, pdo

DBMSes only allow values as parameters for prepared statements. However, table, column, and field names are not allowed with prepared statements.  For example:

```
String sql = "Select * from TABLE1 order by ?";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(1, "column_name_1");
```

Such statement is not allowed. What is the reason for DBMSes to not implement filed names in prepared statements?

Comment: The reason is the performance. You should parametrise only things that lead to the same execution plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two reasons that I am aware of:

1. Although details vary per database system, conceptually, when a statement is prepared, it is compiled and checked for correctness (do all tables and columns exist). The server generates a plan which describes which tables to access, which fields to retrieve, indexes to use, etc.

   This means that at prepare time the database system must know which tables and fields it needs to access, therefore parameterization of tables and fields is not possible. And even if it where technically possible, it would be inefficient, because statement compilation would need to be deferred until execution, essentially throwing away one of the primary reasons for using prepared statements: reusable query plans for better performance.

   And consider this: if table names and field names are allowed to parameterized, why not function names, query fragments, etc?
2. Not allowing parameterization of objects prevents ambiguity. For example in a query with a `where column1 = ?`, if you set the parameter to `peter`, would that be a column name or a string value? That is hard to decide and preventing that ambiguity would make the API harder to use, while the use case of even allowing such parameterization is almost non-existent (and in my experience, the need for such parameterization almost always stem from bad database design).

Allowing parameterization of objects is almost equivalent to just dynamically generating the query and executing it (see also point 1), so why not just forego the additional complexity and disallow parameterization of objects instead.